# Why is Pyplot Specgram Cutting off my Time Axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, formatting

I'm trying out the **`specgarm()`** method from the matplotlib pyplot module.
I created a time-varient signal composed of sine waves in 4 different frequencies and magnigure and wish the spectrogarm can reveal that.

However, the output spectrogram doesn't seem right. Looks like it haves its begining and end of the time axis chopped off. I expected its time axis range from 0 to 1, since that's the duration of my signal, and the length of each time interval should be identical. But I can see that the time interval `[0,0.1]` and `[0.9, 1]` is significantly shorter than the rest. This is the plot I get.
[beginning and end of x axis chopped off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJLNN.png)

I have tried specifying the xtick to the sample time **`t`** returned by **spectgram**, which made it worse like so

[x axis chopped off even worse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDLgE.png)

This is the time response of my signal, which seems legit!
[properly generated signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHa8q.png)
Does anyone have the same problem? I am using python 3.10.2 64-bit on Windows with a matplotlib version of 3.5.3

```
import numpy as np
from math import pi
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#some background settings
sample_freq = 1024
observe_time = 1
n_sample_pt = sample_freq * observe_time
time_line = np.linspace(0, 1, num = n_sample_pt+1)
signal = np.zeros_like(time_line)
#generate signal
f1 = 75
f2 = 100
f3 = 330
f4 = 80
for i, time in enumerate(time_line, start = 0):
    if time < 0.5:
        signal[i] = 3*np.sin(2*pi*f1*time) + 4*np.sin(2*pi*f2*time)
    elif time < 0.7 and time >= 0.5:
        signal[i] = np.sin(2*pi*f3*time) + 7*np.sin(2*pi*f4*time)
    else:
        signal[i] = np.sin(2*pi*f1*time)

(spec_gram, freq, t, image) = plt.specgram(signal, Fs = sample_freq)
plt.title("Spectrogram with Xtick Specified")
plt.xticks(t)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The tick is at the centre of each spectrum, so the time range goes from 0+window/2 to T-window/2, where window is the length of the spectrum and T is the length of the time series.

Comment: @JodyKlymak ahh... I see. Thank you. Guess I have way too little knowledge in spectrograms and I have been so spoiled by Matlab's easyness. So my spectrogarm is actually fine!